# WinApi: Как аварийно выйти из CalBack функции

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть к примеру у меня обычное winapi-шное окно, есть соответственно функция обработки оконных сообщений WindProc.
И вот к примеру в WindProc`е - вызывается функция, ну к примеру SetWindowLongPtr() и предположим вызов это функции завершается ошибкой :

```
  LONG_PTR My_LONG_PTR = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_VSCROLL);
                    
    if (My_LONG_PTR == 0)
    {
    return 1;  //error
    }
```

Вот такой выход через return, как при вызове обычной функции не работает, то есть обратно в WinMain выполнение кода не возвращается. И вот вопрос, как можно или как правильно завершить callback функция в данном случае ?

Comment: Вы хотите завершить приложение?

Comment: KoVadim, по сути да, с выводом ошибки. И после Вашего комментария понял, что похоже нужно просто вызвать функции - DestroyWindow и PostQuitMessage.

Comment: `::std::abort()` или `assert` (для отладочного варианта), кроме того, у вас в примере несоответствие параметров - флаг и стиль должны быть либо оба обычные, либо оба расширенные (ex)

Comment: ExitProcess может быть более оптимальным решением. Возможно

Comment: KoVadim, Спасибо! В итоге все таки сделал через DestroyWindow и PostQuitMessage и запись ошибки GetLastError() в переменную.